# How to pay bus fare in Tallinn?

Tags: money, buses, fares, estonia, tallinn

My father and I are staying in Tallinn, in a flat on Pae street. We don't know the city or the language.

We have used the bus today to go downtown and back. Going downtown, the driver told us to just sit down because we couldn't offer the exact fare (4€); on returning, there was no cash provision at all and the same thing happened, we rode for free.

So now we don't want to rely on this continuing, but as far as we could make out online:

- presold tickets are only available downtown,
- the transport company's app requires a credit card, or else already holding their debit card,
- that fare debit card is supposedly (by website) available at Maxima supermarket near us, but we don't see at the moment how it will be paid/charged up.

We have a German giro card with Maestro, which got employed at a store today but worked only sticking it in, not contactless as the fare gadgets in the bus have it.

**Will we be able to get and charge a bus card tomorrow?** (the store does open)

**How else can we pay?**

Comment: Ok, the whole issue is obsolete for us personally as Dad's sick to his stomach. At least it finally made me sign up to SE.

Comment: Just make sure you have 4 euros in cash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options outlined on [this page](https://visittallinn.ee/eng/visitor/plan/transport/public-transport#where-to-buy-the-different-tickets). The easiest way for a single ticket seems to be to buy a QR ticket [online](https://tallinn.pilet.ee/buy), or use the pilet.ee app on your mobile phone. (Update: I just noticed you need a credit card for the website, too)

When traveling more often, it would probably make sense to buy a prepaid Ühiskaart, a multi day Tallinn Card, or try to use your bank card.

If you don't have a credit card, and your Maestro does not work contactless, the options seem to be limited. I think you may need to go into a physical store that sells bus tickets (see the link above), and pay either in cash, or using your Maestro card. Adding credit to the Ühiskaart should be possible in the same stores.